# I'm looking to create an automated numbering system for custom paint by number kits in photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-script

So I know very little about programming all around. I'm adept at photoshop and I'm looking to automate the numbering system for making these paint by number kits. I convert the images into vector format and set a maximum number of color variations. I then use adobe illustrator to create the outlined partitions of the image by color. This is all well and good, it's automated and efficient as far as I need.

My dilemma is that I do not have a system that can number these partitions in a clear and uniform fashion. I must do this tediously in photoshop, taking hours to finish.

I am looking to create or find a system that will do this last step automatically.

My vison for how this would look would be numbers, 1-20 or so depending on the set color cap, evenly distributed across each partition in uniform font and size. The idea is that there would be a grid of 1 number (this number would be the reference to the color needed in this partition) spread across larger partitions and only a few of 1 number on the smaller partitions. It would hopefully look like so:

[You can see here how tedious this can become.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htici.jpg)

I don't know how to accomplish this, but I'm wondering how complicated this process would be in theory and would it be better for me to learn how to do it myself, hire a professional, or continue the hand numbering. It's creating a labor cap on my small business that is preventing me from further growth.

Any and all help is very much appreciated; if I can provide more context or specifications I would be more than happy to do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with script to some degree. It will work fine for simply forms. But for complicated forms it will be too hard to calculate where you need to put all numbers and how many number will be enough.

But I saw [scripts that can fill any form with any symbols](http://vectorboom.com/load/tips/techniques/how_to_distribute_shapes_within_another_shape_in_illustrator/16-1-0-470). So it's possible to fill any form with numbers, I think, technically.

Of course, if you aren't a seasoned coder it makes no sense to try to do it at home. You need a pro (not even me).

And I see another very simply options as well:

[image]

It doesn't even need a script. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I've managed to tweak old Johnware's script (Circle Fill). Now it can fill with given letters (numbers for example). It works to a degree, but the result far from ideal:

[image]

Probably it can be used for start.

I believe a real programmer could make it way better.

My tweaked version of the script is here: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Ze4-1DQoNRVF1g

---

### Update

I'm improved the script further. Now it:

- works more precise
- handles several selected paths
- remembers values in the dialog window
- sets font size

[image]

Here is the is the updated version of the script: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/0pcpLDGrfQKMJA

---

It took me about 15 minutes to do this:

[image]

But I had to to split some complex paths with a `Knife` tool. Sometimes the script throws a some mystical error. I've just selected another set of paths an run the scripts again and again.

It is not a final result but it's close. I think it's much faster that to do it manually.

Comment: Trust me Yuri, I care! I've been chewing over your earlier responses trying to see how far I could get with them before coming back to you with questions. Your latest version looks very much like what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay. But you would comment it somehow, vote up, give some feedback, etc. Otherwise it makes me look like another wack-job (which I am, probably, but it's another matter). I've added the link to the updated script. Beware, the script can give strange glitches sometimes, there is quite tricky mathematics behind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) just select another set of objects and run the script again in that cases.

Comment: Thanks Yuri! The Delaunay Triangulation tactic was clever, I’ll try to get it functioning with my method as soon as I get to my computer! Thank you again for all your help man.

Comment: Also, I cant upvote quite yet as I don't have enough reputation to do so :)

Comment: This works great! Is it able to run on multiple selected objects at once (so say I have five different areas of the same color- can it run on all five areas at once)?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you previously stated that it ran on several selected paths, but I haven't been successful in getting it to do so. Do you have any tips on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: First version work with one path. Updated version should work with several (any) selected paths. I can't think what there could went wrong. Just select a couple paths and run the file `CharactersFill_v2.jsx`. If you show me your file I can see, if there is something wrong with the paths? Or maybe you could try to change sizes in the dialog window.

Comment: Yes, it's the v2 file that I'm trying to run on a couple of paths, but can't get it to work. It also doesn't work on more complex shapes. It brings up the input window, but when I click on OK nothing happens. Would it make a difference that I'm working on a Mac?

Comment: As you can see my screenshots were taken on Mac as well. And I tried it on Win. It woks on both systems. Did you try to set another sizes? I don't know how big your paths are. If they too small script can give no result. Technically it still draws many circles and then put in center of every circle the character and removes all circles.

Comment: Post your file (or some paths from your file) and I will try them on my side.

Comment: Or you can download the zip file via my first link. There is my AI file (matisse.ai which I used for the screenshot) you can try to test the script on it.

Comment: Do you mean the % of total size or the font size? I've tried adjusting both, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Here is a link to the file that I'm working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3meg0wot9ja23vf/Brittany%20Vectorized%20Fill%20Demo.ai?dl=0

Comment: Try to ungroup all. It will work. But the shapes very complex indeed, it will hard to get a good result. Probably it needs some optimizations of the algorithm. I'm afraid it's beyond my qualification. I don't even a real coder. It's just my little hobby. )

Comment: I tried my script on your file. Here is my result: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ydAOH8TCtmxRkw

Comment: OMG- I was rereading all of your suggestions and took another look at the simple solution you proposed that involved the swatches. I played with that for a little bit and created patterned swatches, which I used to replace the color fill. It works like a charm!!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1ptl3y8knt750i/Vector%20Test%202.svg?dl=0

Comment: I truly can't than you enough for all of the time and effort you have put into helping me solve this problem!!