# Drawing random shapes within a complex vector shape using InDeesign scripting and or basil.js

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I am wondering if there is a simple way to draw a series of random ellipses (or other things) within a complex vector shape (say, a letterform) using basil.js or indesign scripting. I figured out how to place random sized and colored ellipses within a larger ellipse by using if statements and checking the distance of my random ellipses from the center fo the larger ellipse. But I can't for the life of me figure out a way to get my script to check and see if the random ellipses I am drawing fall within a more complex shape. Any help would be appreciated!

So this is what I have working as far as placing random ellipses within a larger ellipse:
[image]

And here is my code for that:

```
function stippleCircle(mR, rR, xP, yP, num){

for(i=0; i<num; i++){
    noStroke();
    println("stip " + i);

    var eRad = mR; //maximum ellipse radius
    var ranRad = rR //radius for small ellipses
    var xPos = xP; //x position of large ellipse
    var yPos = yP; //y position of large ellipse
    var eRad = 0;
    
    var xRan = random(xPos - eRad, xPos + eRad);
    var yRan = random(yPos - eRad, yPos + eRad);

    if(xRan <= xPos && yRan <= yPos){
        if((xPos-xRan) * (xPos-xRan) + (yRan-yPos) * (yRan-yPos) <= eRad * eRad){
            fill(100, 0, 0, 0); //C
            var myEllipse = ellipse(xRan, yRan, ranRad, ranRad);
        }
    }else if(xRan > xPos && yRan <= yPos){
        if((xRan-xPos) * (xRan-xPos) + (yRan-yPos) * (yRan-yPos) <= eRad * eRad){
            fill(0, 100, 0, 0); //M
            var myEllipse = ellipse(xRan, yRan, ranRad, ranRad);
        }
    }else if(xRan > xPos && yRan > yPos){
        if((xRan-xPos) * (xRan-xPos) + (yPos-yRan) * (yPos-yRan) <= eRad * eRad){
            fill(0, 0, 100, 0); //Y
            var myEllipse = ellipse(xRan, yRan, ranRad, ranRad);
        }
    }else if(xRan <= xPos && yRan > yPos){
        if((xPos-xRan) * (xPos-xRan) + (yPos-yRan) * (yPos-yRan) <= eRad * eRad){
            fill(0, 0, 0, 100);
            var myEllipse = ellipse(xRan, yRan, ranRad, ranRad);
        }
    }

    blendMode(myEllipse, BlendMode.SOFT_LIGHT); 
    opacity(myEllipse, 70);
}
```

But how would I go about doing something similar with a more complex shape? The example below is illustrating this with the letter P and would likely use pathsToPoints() or something like that. Is this even possible? Maybe I should start with a vector shape that is simpler than a letter but more complex than an ellipse.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share a couple of screenshots at least. What do you mean 'ellipse within a more complex shape'? There could be many interpretation in case the real complex shapes. For example: https://imgur.com/LYU3k8d.png

Comment: @Axman6 Updated my post, let me know if that clarifies it any further.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Updated my post, let me know if that clarifies it any further.

Comment: Probably you can adapt the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026417/im-looking-to-create-an-automated-numbering-system-for-custom-paint-by-number-k/68027687#68027687

Comment: @itsphuckinjosh Looks great, thanks for that!