# Paint with numbers with Adobe Illustrator Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

**Hello thanks to moluapple, I got this script from the adobe support community, I'm a beginner in javascript but I have a task to make, I have to paint numbers in each color of the image, actually, I see that in this solution brings me numbers in each layer, but doesn't work for the colors, can someone has a similar solution?**

Let me add the expected result which is for each color on the picture the script adds a number to the color 1 for green 2 for yellow etc, let me show you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKm1o.jpg)

*here is the original link*

https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/script-insert-text-number-in-the-middle-of-visible-bounds-of-the-each-object/td-p/8088914/page/3

```
(function() {
var doc = app.activeDocument,
    lays = doc.layers,
    WORK_LAY = lays.add(),
    NUM_LAY = lays.add(),
    i = lays.length - 1,
    lay;

// main working loop
for (; i > 1; i--) {
    //process each layer
    lay = lays[i];
    lay.name = lay.name + " Num:" + (i - 1); // i-1 as 2 layers beed added.
    process(lay.pathItems, false);
    process(lay.compoundPathItems, true); // if any
}
//clean up
NUM_LAY.name = "Numbers";
WORK_LAY.remove();

function process(items, isCompound) {
    var j = 0,
        b, xy, s, p, op;

    for (; j < items.length; j++) {
        // process each pathItem
        op = items[j];
        // add stroke
        if (isCompound) {
            strokeComPath(op);
        } else {
            !op.closed && op.closed = true;
            op.filled = false;
            op.stroked = true;
        };
        b = getCenterBounds(op);
        xy = [b[0] + (b[2] - b[0]) / 2, b[1] + (b[3] - b[1]) / 2];
        s = (
            Math.min(op.height, op.width) < 20 ||
            (op.area && Math.abs(op.area) < 150)
            ) ? 4 : 6; // adjust font size for small area paths.
        add_nums(i - 1, xy, s);
    }
}

function getMinVisibleSize(b) {
    var s = Math.min(b[2] - b[0], b[1] - b[3]);
    return Math.abs(s);
}

function getGeometricCenter(p) {
    var b = p.geometricBounds;
    return [(b[0] + b[2]) / 2, (b[1] + b[3]) / 2];
}

// returns square of distance between p1 and p2
function getDist2(p1, p2) {
    return Math.pow(p1[0] + p2[0], 2) + Math.pow(p1[1] + p2[1], 2);
}

// returns visibleBounds of a path in a compoundPath p
// which is closest to center of the original path op
function findBestBounds(op, p) {
    var opc = getGeometricCenter(op);
    var idx = 0,
        d;
    var minD = getDist2(opc, getGeometricCenter(p.pathItems[0]));
    for (var i = 0, iEnd = p.pathItems.length; i < iEnd; i++) {
        d = getDist2(opc, getGeometricCenter(p.pathItems[i]));
        if (d < minD) {
            minD = d;
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    return p.pathItems[idx].visibleBounds;
}

function applyOffset(op, checkBounds) {
    var p = op.duplicate(WORK_LAY, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING),
        // offset value the small the better, but meantime more slow. 
        offset = function() {
            var minsize = Math.min(p.width, p.height);
            if (minsize >= 50) {
                return '-1'
            } else if (20 < minsize && minsize < 50) {
                return '-0.5'
            } else {
                return '-0.2' // 0.2 * 2 (both side ) * 50 (Times) = 20
            }
        },
        xmlstring = '<LiveEffect name="Adobe Offset Path"><Dict data="I jntp 2 R mlim 4 R ofst #offset"/></LiveEffect>'
        .replace('#offset', offset()),
        TIMES = 100; // if shapes are too large, should increase the value.

    if (checkBounds) {
        // check its size only if it needs, because it's too slow
        while (TIMES-- && getMinVisibleSize(p.visibleBounds) > 3) p.applyEffect(xmlstring);
    } else {
        while (TIMES--) p.applyEffect(xmlstring);
    }
    return p;
}

function getCenterBounds(op) {
    var originalMinSize = getMinVisibleSize(op.visibleBounds);

    var p = applyOffset(op, false);

    if (getMinVisibleSize(p.visibleBounds) > originalMinSize) {
        // in some cases, path p becomes larger for some unknown reason
        p.remove();
        p = applyOffset(op, true);
    }

    var b = p.visibleBounds;

    if (getMinVisibleSize(b) > 10) {
        activeDocument.selection = [p];
        executeMenuCommand("expandStyle");
        p = activeDocument.selection[0];
        if (p.typename == "CompoundPathItem") {
            b = findBestBounds(op, p);
        }
    }

    p.remove();
    return b;
}

function add_nums(n, xy, s) {
    var txt = NUM_LAY.textFrames.add();

    txt.contents = n;
    txt.textRange.justification = Justification.CENTER;
    txt.textRange.characterAttributes.size = s;
    txt.position = [xy[0] - txt.width / 2, xy[1] + txt.height / 2];
}

function strokeComPath(compoundPath) {
    var p = compoundPath.pathItems,
        l = p.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < l; i++) {
        !p[i].closed && p[i].closed = true;
        p[i].stroked = true;
        p[i].filled = false;
    };
}
```

})();

Comment: Here are a couple solution of the similar task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026417/im-looking-to-create-an-automated-numbering-system-for-custom-paint-by-number-k

Comment: Please, show how your original file looks like and how the desired result should look like.

Comment: As a quick solution you can put every color on separate layer (use the command ‘select objects with the same color’) and you will get exactly the result you have on the picture. If you don’t want to fiddle with layers it will need to change the code significantly. Let me know if you need it

Comment: I see, my task is to automatize the task so I need the changes in the code if you can help me I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you're trying to gain. So here is a guess:

If you change the function `process()` this way:

```
function process(items, isCompound) {
    var j = 0,
        b, xy, s, p, op;

    for (; j < items.length; j++) {
        // process each pathItem
        op = items[j];
        c = op.fillColor;                       // <--- here
        color = 'CMYK ' +                       // <--- here
            [   Math.round(c.cyan),             // <--- here
                Math.round(c.magenta),          // <--- here
                Math.round(c.yellow),           // <--- here
                Math.round(c.black)             // <--- here
            ].join(',');                        // <--- here
        // add stroke
        if (isCompound) {
            strokeComPath(op);
        } else {
            !op.closed && op.closed = true;
            // op.filled = false;               // <--- here
            // op.stroked = true;               // <--- here
        };
        b = getCenterBounds(op);
        xy = [b[0] + (b[2] - b[0]) / 2, b[1] + (b[3] - b[1]) / 2];
        s = (
            Math.min(op.height, op.width) < 20 ||
            (op.area && Math.abs(op.area) < 150)
            ) ? 4 : 6; // adjust font size for small area paths.

        // add_nums(i - 1 + color, xy, s);
        add_nums(color, xy, s);                 // <--- here
    }
}
```

It will put CMYK percents inside the shapes instead of numbers.

[image]

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help Yuri, but I added a picture about the desired result :) hope you get the idea of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another modification of the main function `process()`. It's turned out that it can be done if you add & modify just two lines:

```
function process(items, isCompound) {
    var j = 0,
        b, xy, s, p, op;

    for (; j < items.length; j++) {
        // process each pathItem
        op = items[j];
        try { color = op.fillColor.spot.name } catch(e) { continue } // <-- HERE
        // add stroke
        if (isCompound) {
            strokeComPath(op);
        } else {
            !op.closed && op.closed = true;
            op.filled = false;
            op.stroked = true;
        };
        b = getCenterBounds(op);
        xy = [b[0] + (b[2] - b[0]) / 2, b[1] + (b[3] - b[1]) / 2];
        s = (
            Math.min(op.height, op.width) < 20 ||
            (op.area && Math.abs(op.area) < 150)
            ) ? 4 : 6; // adjust font size for small area paths.

        add_nums(color, xy, s); // <--- HERE
    }
}
```

And the colors should be Spot Global colors. The script put in the middle of every shape a name of the swatch color.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yuri, it works thanks a lot for your help! hope I learn more about Javascript in a short time :)

Comment: I'm glad. Wish good luck to you. I'm not even a pro coder actually. I'm a book designer. Have learned Javascript via reading and changing someone's else scripts mostly. And feel free to consider to accept my answer as long as it works fine https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer