# Paint by number Illustrator script

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am from supercoloring and we decided to convert our vector illustrations in color to color by number worksheets. Our input files are color and outline images in svg format.
Outline version (like a coloring page) + Color version

[outline version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJqS.png) and
[color version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVOQe.png)

What we want to get is the following

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXhV.png)

We would like that a color palette is generated under the outline version of the image based on the color data from the color version of the image. Moreover, numbers corresponding to this palette are placed inside each color space of the outlined version.
I understand that no script in the world would do this properly, but at least I am striving to reduce the time spent by the editor (person) to put these numbers manually in the Illustrator. I understand that our color vector images may have too many colors and shades so we need somehow to limit the result colors of the palette ( to fuse them into large groups of basic colors).

I searched all over the stackoverflow solutions and found some ingenious like [Paint with numbers with Adobe Illustrator Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73705368/paint-with-numbers-with-adobe-illustrator-javascript) and
[I'm looking to create an automated numbering system for custom paint by number kits in photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026417/im-looking-to-create-an-automated-numbering-system-for-custom-paint-by-number-k) (Kudos to Yuri Khristich). However, they are not exactly adapted to our needs.
Most of scripts on the web generate outlined images from color version, but the quality is compromised. We have already a proper outline version that we want to use as a base for color by number worksheet.

Comment: You can see 3 samples with input and output data here [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONgGcGxBBOhlzyQ5ELLJgNfw-7RneczL/view?usp=sharing](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://productivista.com/make-a-list-of-colors-from-your-selection/) is the script to make a 'color palette' for selected artwork.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68026417/im-looking-to-create-an-automated-numbering-system-for-custom-paint-by-number-k), as you know, is the script to add color names to all filled areas.

So I took the two script, made a couple of minimal tweaks and get almost the result you want. All you need after the scripts is to copy the layer with numbers and 'palette' from a colored artwork to a outline version.

**Script #1**

```
// Modified version
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75344674/paint-by-number-illustrator-script

// Original: 
// https://productivista.com/make-a-list-of-colors-from-your-selection/

/*
  Date: July, 2020
  Author: Katja Bjerrum, email: katja@productivista.com, www.productivista.com
  ============================================================================
  NOTICE:
  This script is provided "as is" without warranty of any kind.
  Free to use, not for sale.
  ============================================================================
  Released under the MIT license.
  http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  ============================================================================

*/

//@target illustrator

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myLayer = doc.activeLayer;
app.coordinateSystem = CoordinateSystem.ARTBOARDCOORDINATESYSTEM;
var swGrps = doc.swatchGroups;
var mainSwGr = doc.swatchGroups[0];
var sel = doc.selection;

var actionSet = 'CreateSwatchGroup';
var actionName = 'ColourGroup';
var actionPath = Folder.myDocuments + '/Adobe Scripts/';

if (!Folder(actionPath).exists) Folder(actionPath).create();
//app.doScript("Colorgroup", "ToSwatchScript"); // Action, that creates swatch group

var actionDoc =
  [ '/version 3',
    '/name [' + actionSet.length  + ' ' + ascii2Hex(actionSet) + ']',
    '/isOpen 1',
    '/actionCount 1',
    '/action-1 {',
    '/name [' + actionName.length + ' ' + ascii2Hex(actionName) + ']',
    '   /keyIndex 0',
    '   /colorIndex 0',
    '   /isOpen 1',
    '   /eventCount 1',
    '   /event-1 {',
    '     /useRulersIn1stQuadrant 0',
    '     /internalName (ai_plugin_swatches)',
    '     /localizedName [ 8',
    '       5377617463686573',
    '     ]',
    '     /isOpen 0',
    '     /isOn 1',
    '     /hasDialog 1',
    '     /showDialog 1',
    '     /parameterCount 1',
    '     /parameter-1 {',
    '       /key 1835363957',
    '       /showInPalette 4294967295',
    '       /type (enumerated)',
    '       /name [ 15',
    '         4e657720436f6c6f722047726f7570',
    '       ]',
    '      /value 17',
    '     }',
    '   }',
    '}'].join('');

createAction(actionDoc, actionName, actionPath);

app.redraw();
app.doScript (actionName, actionSet);
app.redraw();
app.unloadAction(actionSet, '');


var convMM = 2.8346456692; // initialization of the variable to convert points to mm

var colorgroup = doc.swatchGroups[doc.swatchGroups.length - 1]; // Choose the last swatch group
var stY = -200; //
var stX = 20;
var recW = 25;
var recH = 25;

var offX = recW / 5;
var offY = recH / 4;
var textoffY = recH / 4;
var rows = 4;
var cols = 4;

var black = new GrayColor();
black.gray = 80;
var white = new GrayColor() ;
white.gray = 0;
var noStroke = doc.swatches[0].color;

if (swGrps.length <=1){
    alert ("Please create swatch group from your selection");
}
else if (sel <= 0){
    //docRef.placedItems[0].selected == false;
    alert ("Please make a selection");
    delSwatchGr(colorgroup); //delete swatch group
}
else{
    swatchGroupList(colorgroup, stY, stX);//create corlor list
    // delSwatchGr(colorgroup);//delete swatch group
}


//Function, that creates color list
function swatchGroupList(swatchGroup, stY, stX) {

    // Groups everything in the list
    var mainGroup = myLayer.groupItems.add();
    mainGroup.name = "Colors";
    mainGroup.moveToBeginning(myLayer);

    //Name of the color list
    var nameText = myLayer.textFrames.add();
    nameText.contents = swatchGroup.name; // the name of the swatch group
    nameText.position = [stX, stY + recH];

    var nameStyle = nameText.textRange.characterAttributes;
    nameStyle.size = 12;//size in punkt
    //nameStyle.textFont = textFonts.getByName("Avenir-Book");//the font
    nameStyle.capitalization = FontCapsOption.ALLCAPS;//ALL CAPITALS

    var swatches = swatchGroup.getAllSwatches();
    var swatchArray = [];

    for (i = swatches.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        var mySwatch = swatches[i];
        mySwatch.name = i + 1;
        var subGroup = createSwatchGroup(mySwatch, textoffY);
        swatchArray.push(subGroup);
    }

    nameText.moveToEnd(mainGroup);
    var myGroup = swatchArray;
    var maxW = maxWidth(myGroup);


    for (var j = 0; j < myGroup.length; j++) {
        var mySubGroup = myGroup[j];
        mySubGroup.moveToBeginning(mainGroup);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < mainGroup.groupItems.length; i++) {
        var mySubGroup = mainGroup.groupItems[i];

        if (mainGroup.groupItems.length > 7) {
            rows = 7;
            var c = i%rows;
            var r = Math.floor(i/rows);
            mySubGroup.position = [stX + r * (maxW + 10), stY - c * (recH + offY)];
        }
        else {
            rows = 7;
            var c = i % rows;
            var r = Math.floor(i / rows);
            mySubGroup.position = [stX, stY - c * (recH + offY)];
        }
    }
    // textSwatch.moveToBeginning(SubGroup);
    // path_ref.moveToBeginning(SubGroup);
    // SubGroup.position = [stX + c * 140, stY - r * (path_ref.height + offY)];
    subGroup.moveToBeginning(mainGroup);

}

function lightColor(c){
    if(c.typename)
    {
       switch(c.typename)
       {
            case "CMYKColor":
            return (c.black>=10 || c.cyan>10 || c.magenta>10 || c.yellow > 10) ? true : false;
            case "RGBColor":
            return (c.red<230  || c.green<230 || c.blue<230) ? true : false;
            case "GrayColor":
            return c.gray >= 10 ? true : false;
            case "SpotColor":
            return lightColor(c.spot.color);

            //return false;
       }
   }
}

function fitItem(item, itemW, itemH, diff) {
    var oldWidth = item.width
    var oldHeight = item.height

    if (item.width > item.height) {
      // landscape, scale height using ratio from width
      item.width = itemW - diff.deltaX
      var ratioW = item.width / oldWidth
      item.height = oldHeight * ratioW
    } else {
      // portrait, scale width using ratio from height
      item.height = itemH - diff.deltaY
      var ratioH = item.height / oldHeight
      item.width = oldWidth * ratioH
    }

  }

  function itemBoundsDiff(item) {
    var itemVB = item.visibleBounds

    var itemVW = itemVB[2] - itemVB[0] // right - left
    var itemVH = itemVB[1] - itemVB[3] // top - bottom

    var itemGB = item.geometricBounds

    var itemGW = itemGB[2] - itemGB[0] // right - left
    var itemGH = itemGB[1] - itemGB[3] // top - bottom

    var deltaX = itemVW - itemGW
    var deltaY = itemVH - itemGH

    var diff = { deltaX: deltaX, deltaY: deltaY }

    return diff
  }

  function delSwatchGr(swGr){

        var swGrSws = swGr.getAllSwatches();
        for (var j = 0; j < swGrSws.length; j++){
            var sw = swGrSws[j];
            sw.color = new CMYKColor();
        }
        swGr.remove();

}

//Function finds the max group width
function maxWidth(myGroup) {
    var maxFound = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < myGroup.length; j++) {
        var GrWidth = myGroup[j].width;
        //var Widthmax = GrWidth.width;
        maxFound = Math.max(maxFound, GrWidth);
    }
    return maxFound;
}

function createSwatchGroup(sw, myOffset) {
    //Is "MyForm" path exists?
    try{
        var path_ref_ori = app.activeDocument.pathItems.getByName("MyForm" || "myform" || "MYFORM");
    }
    catch(e) {
        var path_ref_ori = false;
    }

    if (path_ref_ori) {
        myPath = path_ref_ori.duplicate();
        var boundsDiff = itemBoundsDiff(myPath);
        fitItem(myPath, recW, recH, boundsDiff);
        myPath.name = "NewForm";
        myPath.position = [0, 0];
    }
    else {
        var myPath = createMyPath()
    }

    myPath.fillColor = sw.color;
    myPath.stroked = true;
    myPath.strokeWidth = 0.3;
    myPath.strokeColor = lightColor(myPath.fillColor) ? noStroke : black;

    var textSwatch = myLayer.textFrames.add(); //swatch text
    textSwatch.contents = sw.name;

    textSwatch.position = [myPath.width + 1.3 * convMM, -myOffset];
    var textSwStyle = textSwatch.textRange.characterAttributes;
    textSwStyle.size = 10; //size in punkt
    //textSwStyle.textFont = textFonts.getByName("MyriadPro-Semibold"); //the font

    var SubGroup = myLayer.groupItems.add(); //groups path and text
    SubGroup.name = sw.name;
    SubGroup.position = [0, 0];

    textSwatch.moveToBeginning(SubGroup);
    myPath.moveToBeginning(SubGroup);

    return SubGroup;
}


function createMyPath(){
//Is "MyForm" path exists?
    try{
        var path_ref_ori = app.activeDocument.pathItems.getByName("MyForm" || "myform" || "MYFORM");
    }
    catch(e) {
        var path_ref_ori = false;
    }

    if (path_ref_ori) {
        path_ref = path_ref_ori.duplicate();
        var boundsDiff = itemBoundsDiff(path_ref);
        fitItem(path_ref, recW, recH, boundsDiff);
        path_ref.name = "NewForm";
        path_ref.position = [0, 0];
    }
    else {
        var path_ref = myLayer.pathItems.rectangle(0, 0, recW, recH); //swatch path item
    }

    return path_ref
};

function createAction(str, set, path) {
    var f = new File('' + path + '/' + set + '.aia');
    f.open('w');
    f.write(str);
    f.close();
    app.loadAction(f);
    f.remove();
};

function ascii2Hex(hex) {
    return hex.replace(/./g, function (a) { return a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) });
};
```

Input (after select the artwork and run the script):

[image]

Result (added the global swatches and the 'color palette' at the bottom):

[image]

**Script #2**

```
// Based on:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73705368/paint-with-numbers-with-adobe-illustrator-javascript

var doc = app.activeDocument,
    lays = doc.layers,
    WORK_LAY = lays.add(),
    NUM_LAY = lays.add(),
    i = lays.length - 1,
    lay;

// main working loop
for (; i > 1; i--) {
    //process each layer
    lay = lays[i];
    lay.name = lay.name + " Num:" + (i - 1); // i-1 as 2 layers beed added.
    process(lay.pathItems, false);
    process(lay.compoundPathItems, true); // if any
}
//clean up
NUM_LAY.name = "Numbers";
WORK_LAY.remove();

function process(items, isCompound) {
    var j = 0,
        b, xy, s, p, op;

    for (; j < items.length; j++) {
        // process each pathItem
        op = items[j];
        try { color = op.fillColor.spot.name } catch(e) { continue } // <-- HERE
        // add stroke
        if (isCompound) {
            // strokeComPath(op);
        } else {
            // !op.closed && op.closed = true;
            // op.filled = false;
            // op.stroked = true;
        };
        b = getCenterBounds(op);
        xy = [b[0] + (b[2] - b[0]) / 2, b[1] + (b[3] - b[1]) / 2];
        s = (
            Math.min(op.height, op.width) < 20 ||
            (op.area && Math.abs(op.area) < 150)
            ) ? 20 : 40; // adjust font size for small area paths.
        add_nums(color, xy, s); // <--- HERE
    }
}

function getMinVisibleSize(b) {
    var s = Math.min(b[2] - b[0], b[1] - b[3]);
    return Math.abs(s);
}

function getGeometricCenter(p) {
    var b = p.geometricBounds;
    return [(b[0] + b[2]) / 2, (b[1] + b[3]) / 2];
}

// returns square of distance between p1 and p2
function getDist2(p1, p2) {
    return Math.pow(p1[0] + p2[0], 2) + Math.pow(p1[1] + p2[1], 2);
}

// returns visibleBounds of a path in a compoundPath p
// which is closest to center of the original path op
function findBestBounds(op, p) {
    var opc = getGeometricCenter(op);
    var idx = 0,
        d;
    var minD = getDist2(opc, getGeometricCenter(p.pathItems[0]));
    for (var i = 0, iEnd = p.pathItems.length; i < iEnd; i++) {
        d = getDist2(opc, getGeometricCenter(p.pathItems[i]));
        if (d < minD) {
            minD = d;
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    return p.pathItems[idx].visibleBounds;
}

function applyOffset(op, checkBounds) {
    var p = op.duplicate(WORK_LAY, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING),
        // offset value the small the better, but meantime more slow.
        offset = function() {
            var minsize = Math.min(p.width, p.height);
            if (minsize >= 50) {
                return '-1'
            } else if (20 < minsize && minsize < 50) {
                return '-0.5'
            } else {
                return '-0.2' // 0.2 * 2 (both side ) * 50 (Times) = 20
            }
        },
        xmlstring = '<LiveEffect name="Adobe Offset Path"><Dict data="I jntp 2 R mlim 4 R ofst #offset"/></LiveEffect>'
        .replace('#offset', offset()),
        TIMES = 100; // if shapes are too large, should increase the value.

    if (checkBounds) {
        // check its size only if it needs, because it's too slow
        while (TIMES-- && getMinVisibleSize(p.visibleBounds) > 3) p.applyEffect(xmlstring);
    } else {
        while (TIMES--) p.applyEffect(xmlstring);
    }
    return p;
}

function getCenterBounds(op) {
    var originalMinSize = getMinVisibleSize(op.visibleBounds);

    var p = applyOffset(op, false);

    if (getMinVisibleSize(p.visibleBounds) > originalMinSize) {
        // in some cases, path p becomes larger for some unknown reason
        p.remove();
        p = applyOffset(op, true);
    }

    var b = p.visibleBounds;

    if (getMinVisibleSize(b) > 10) {
        activeDocument.selection = [p];
        executeMenuCommand("expandStyle");
        p = activeDocument.selection[0];
        if (p.typename == "CompoundPathItem") {
            b = findBestBounds(op, p);
        }
    }

    p.remove();
    return b;
}

function add_nums(n, xy, s) {
    var txt = NUM_LAY.textFrames.add();

    txt.contents = n;
    txt.textRange.justification = Justification.CENTER;
    txt.textRange.characterAttributes.size = s;
    txt.position = [xy[0] - txt.width / 2, xy[1] + txt.height / 2];
}

function strokeComPath(compoundPath) {
    var p = compoundPath.pathItems,
        l = p.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < l; i++) {
        // !p[i].closed && p[i].closed = true;
        // p[i].stroked = true;
        // p[i].filled = false;
    }
};
```

Result (added the layer with numbers after run the script):

[image]

Final outlined version with numbers and the 'color palette'

[image]

Note: you have to ungroup and unmask the color artwork before you run the Script #2.

Here is the results for the rest examples:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the 'final' artwork still need a quite amount of additional manual work: to move or remove extra numbers.

And it makes sense to reduce the number of colors in original color artworks (perhaps it's possible to do with a script to some extent, as well).

Comment: I see. I will probably skip the second script. I mean we generate the palette, remove manually redundant colors from it, rearrange numbers. Then we place the palette on the outlined version and start putting numbers on it. At least, we save time by generating a palette at once.

Comment: Yuri, can you tell the reason why the second script did not work for this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BuauFgnb2XN55SaTCafoYYme7MsGFzYW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to uncomment: `!op.closed && op.closed = true;` at the line 35 and 148.

Comment: Just in case I've made the modified version of the second script that picks only selected objects (except compound paths, though). It can be useful to add numbers in the 'semi-automatic' mode: select the object(s) you want to process, run the script and get the numbers (color names, actually) for these objects only. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I7-E2xmG03LCmqavdrXI46Dxw1z3iYjs/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Thank you, Yuri. Your scripts will reduce the manual work of the editor for sure.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Let me know if you have problems.